# do more headers mean better chance the server thinks you're a human

Tags: python, http, web-scraping, python-requests, http-headers

This is not a programming related question, but I've used `python` `requests` a lot of times.

The headers I usually use are:

- accept-encoding
- origin
- referrer
- user-agent
- accept-language
- accept
- cookie

While examining the requests sent to a server when performing a task such as logging in, you notice headers like:

- Host
- content-length
- TE

If I decided to add these headers to my requests, would it improve my chance of being recognized as a human since it tells the server information about the "browser".

Answer (score 2):

Not really.

`Host` is a required header in HTTP v.1.1 protocol, so it is sent anyway. The `requests` module sets this header implicitly. You should not set it manually and in 99 cases of 100 you should never care about this header.

Although `Content-Length` is an optional header, it is being used almost all the time, because it is the easiest way to tell the remote server where HTTP message actually ends. The most popular alternative is `Transfer-Encoding: chunked`. Any of these two headers do not disclose any information about the client, so you should not worry about them.

Finally, by using `TE` header client tells the remote server the desired `Transfer-Encoding` format. Again, this header just negotiates data format between client and server, it will hardly improve your chances to be recognized as a human.